# Nash equilibrium with mutually exclusive actions

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, reference-request

consider a zero-sum game where action space for both players are the same. I want to compute the equilibrium under the constraint that players do not use the same action. For example, if player 1's equilibrium mixed strategy involves actions {a,b,c}, player 2's mixed strategy cannot have {a,b,c} in her mixed strategy at the equilibrium. How can I compute such an equilibrium? Are there any prior works on such constrained Nash equilibria in zero sum games?

Comment: A nontrivial zero-sum game cannit be a symmetric game, so the labels one assigns do not have any special meaning.

Comment: Are you saying that 1. the equilibrium is not symmetric, meaning players could choose the same action but they happen not to or 2. player 2 is actually prohibited from choosing any action player 1 played, thus the game is not simultaneous, since player 1's choice has to preceed player 2's for this statement to have meaning?

Comment: Every Nash-equilbrium in a zero-sum game in which both players have the same number of actions satisfies the condition up to relabeling iff the total number of actions in the two supports is not larger than the number of actions of each player.

Comment: what I mean is player 2 is prohibited from choosing an action player 1 chooses and vice versa. It's simply an anti-coordination game+ zero-sum game which makes it a nonzero sum game but in a special, structured way.

Comment: But who moves first? How is vice versa possible without time travel?

Comment: I believe the question is better stated as: "Conditional on it existing, how do I compute a Nash equilibria on symmetric zero-sum games which satisfies the non-overlapping support conditions?"

Comment: yes, exactly. I also want to analyze the existence of pure equilibrium for a quasi concave utility, typical proof by fixed point theorem won't work since supports are not convex sets...